# Работа с базой данных Android

Tags: java, android

Как сделать в приложении такую вещь, например: 
Выходит регистрация, вы регистрируетесь, а когда в следующий раз зайдете этого окна регистрации больше не будет.

Comment: если ответ помог, прошу отмечать его как правильный, согласно правилам.

Answer (score 4):

Можно для этого использовать `SharedPreference` куда вы например сохраните ID вошедшего пользователя, а при запуске приложения будете проверять значения которое храниться по тегу ID в `SharedPreference` и если оно есть то грузите новое `activity`, а если оно равно значению по-умолчанию то показываете экран регистрации. Так же с выходом, вы просто записываете в  ID значение по-умолчанию, тем самым показывая что пользователя нет в системе(приложении).

[Хороший урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences) по тому, как пользоваться SharedPreference

Comment: Мне не то что бы регистрация нужна, а скорее: 
Выбирает пользователь себе роль, а после играет в эту роль. При другом запуске приложения ему уже не будет доступен выбор ролей, а будет уже сама игра. Хотя, принцип один и тот же, да?

Comment: @user207012 да,  верно, принцип один и тот же.